# What is an audio output transformer? Is it the same thing as an impedance matching transformer?

Tags: transformer, impedance-matching

What is meant by an audio output transformer, does it mean that it is designed to operate at audio frequency or to match impedance?

Comment: I'm trying to think of a case where an audio output transformer isn't used for impedance matching. And the only other case I can think of right now is when it is used for isolation (for example, those used in the old copper wire telephone systems.) Otherwise, it's about impedance matching. It is also supposed to be used at audio frequencies, though. So this isn't an either/or situation. The old vacuum tube plate impedances just didn't match up with speakers, so in those systems and at those times an output transformer was a necessity.

Comment: The terms aren't exactly equivalent because you may need impedance matching transformers at the input, or between stages too.

Answer (score 9):

> designed to operate at audio frequency or to match impedance?

Both. The specification of a transformer covers both its frequency range, and its turns ratio.

It gets more difficult to design a transformer as its frequency range increases.

The low frequency end is inductance limited, you need enough turns, and a high permeability core to increase the value of the primary inductance to something that doesn't shunt your signal too much.

The high frequency end needs few enough turns to keep the self-resonant frequency well above the top operating frequency, and the core needs thin laminations to keep the core losses down.

Once the core and basic number of turns has been established from the frequency range, then the turns ratio can be modified fairly freely to match impedances.

An audio output transformer matches the \$k\Omega\$ impedance of valve anodes to the single-figure \$\Omega\$ of loudspeakers, however there are many places where other ratios or even 1:1 are used for isolation.

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that at high frequencies leakage inductance is a real pain and can mean that very tight control of the windings is needed to ensure that it doesn't significantly attenuate stuff over 5 kHz.

Answer (score 3):

The Audio Output transformer should respond across the full Audio range for good fidelity .This is why more expensive laminations and more exotic winding techniques are used when compared to power transformers.The audio Output transformer does operate at Audio frequency .Valves would typicaly have impedances in the K ohm range where as the moving coil speakers would have impedances in the Ohm range .5K to 4 ohm would not be uncommon.Hence impedance match is needed.For a single ended Class A valve the transformer HT primary must also be specified to carry the DC Anode current which means an air gap to avoid core saturation.For a pair of pushpull valves the primary is center tapped so the saturation issue is mitigated.Early solid state Audio gear persisted with output transformers .Modern equipment matches the speaker and does not use an Output transformer.Good quality output transformers are large and expensive .

Answer (score 2):

### audio frequency or to match impedance?

**Both f range and impedance parameters are required.**

It may be intended for some impedance as all transformers are;

Each one is designed for many applications

For example ones that have a turns ratio of 1:1 with low loss at 600 Ohms are used for ;   telephone sets, PBXs, DLC systems, central office switches

- Optimized insertion loss and return loss for audio frequency range, including voiceband
- Designed for 600 Ω line impedance

All transformers are designed for a certain R range of \$VA=I^2R\$ which implies a certain impedance, R on either side where power ratings are usually defined as   VA=W+VAR

Answer (score 1):

An audio output transformer connects the output terminals to the internals of the device while providing isolation and/or impedance matching.

It operates at audio frequency carrying the audio signal to its destination.

It could be loudspeaker drive, or a lower level signal going towards a mixer or amplifier that depends on the context.